# Too many indices when I try to extract unique rows from Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have textfiles containing differing amounts of repeat measurements on objects. To process them I only need one of the measurements hence only need a unique row, each measurement ID is in the first column of a row. The code below works on arrays made within the script but not with data I import, I am not sure why.

#### Textfile data:

```
Exp_ID  Height  Weight  Length  Width   Thickness   Comments
3   11.13277    20.4122 89.37035    5.18E-01    8.50E-01    data
3   11.13277    20.4122 89.37035    5.18E-01    8.50E-01    data
7   6.733798    15.46147    90.56544    0.506542    7.64E-01    data
7   9.706813    14.9553 89.91621    5.08E-01    0.75902 data
11  9.11572 17.68755    89.44375    5.42E-01    7.57E-01    data
11  9.025373    21.21589    89.19776    0.542295    7.57E-01    data
15  10.03784    17.97892    89.67505    5.44E-01    8.65E-01    data
15  9.231881    22.52341    89.5358 5.38E-01    0.793483    data
19  8.477057    20.34709    93.26012    5.19E-01    7.79E-01    data
19  8.515575    21.78714    93.23844    5.19E-01    7.79E-01    data
23  8.999844    19.24896    89.66132    5.38E-01    7.77E-01    data
23  8.999808    22.49319    89.63657    5.37E-01    7.79E-01    data
```

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from numpy import nan

def mylistdir(directory):
    """A specialized version of os.listdir() that ignores files that
    start with a leading period."""
    filelist = os.listdir(directory)
    return [x for x in filelist
            if not (x.startswith('.'))]

path=('/Users/username/Desktop/test_data_folder/')


files=mylistdir(path)  
print(files)
print('')


for f in files:
    print(f)
    fname=path+f
    dataA=np.genfromtxt(fname,dtype=float, delimiter='\t',      names=True)
    #dataA=np.loadtxt(fname,dtype=float,      delimiter='\t',skiprows=1,usecols=[0,1,2,3],filling_values=nan)
    print('')
    print(dataA.shape)
    print('ndims = '+ str(dataA.ndim))
    print('')
    dataA_orig = dataA

    headerNames=dataA.dtype.names #this creates a tupe with the header names

    Id = dataA['Exp_ID']
    Height = dataA['Height']
    Weight = dataA['Weight']
    Length = dataA['Length']


    dataA = dataA[dataA[:, 0] == np.roll(dataA, -1, axis=0)[:, 0]]#################
```

#### Error:

File "/Users/username/Desktop/SDN_PYTHON_SCRIPTS/untitled29.py", line 47, in 
    dataA = dataA[dataA[:, 0] == np.roll(dataA, -1, axis=0)[:, 0]]#################

IndexError: too many indices for array

#### Expected output:

```
[3  11.13277    20.4122 89.37035    5.18E-01    8.50E-01    data
7   6.733798    15.46147    90.56544    0.506542    7.64E-01    data
11  9.025373    21.21589    89.19776    0.542295    7.57E-01    data
15  10.03784    17.97892    89.67505    5.44E-01    8.65E-01    data
19  8.477057    20.34709    93.26012    5.19E-01    7.79E-01    data    data
23  8.999808    22.49319    89.63657    5.37E-01    7.79E-01    data]
```

Comment: Hello! Could you specify what happens when you read from csv? "doesn't work" is too generic. If you get a traceback error, plase edit your question to add it.

Comment: Hi Valentino, the error was in the title but I should have been more explicit:                    
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/SDN_PYTHON_SCRIPTS/untitled29.py", line 47, in <module>
    dataA = dataA[dataA[:, 0] == np.roll(dataA, -1, axis=0)[:, 0]]#################

IndexError: too many indices for array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that `np.genfromtx` does not create a 2D array, but a 1D array of tuples. The line `dataA = dataA[dataA[:, 0] == np.roll(dataA, -1, axis=0)[:, 0]]` instead considers `dataA` a 2D array.
Basically you are trying to indexing 2 dimensions in a 1D array. Hence the error.

To make it a 2D array, you could do:

```
dataA2D = np.array([x for row in dataA for x in row])
dataA2D.shape = (dataA.shape[0], len(dataA2D)//dataA.shape[0])
```

Now `dataA2D` is a 2D array with the expected shape. And if you do:

```
out = dataA2D[dataA2D[:, 0] == np.roll(dataA2D, -1, axis=0)[:, 0]]
```

`out` is your expected result.

---

By the way, you could do this much easier using **`pandas`**.
Here is how to do:

```
import pandas as pd
dataA = pd.read_csv(path_of_csv, sep='\s+')
out = dataA.groupby('Exp_ID').first()
```

`path_of_csv` is the string with the path of the file containing the data.

Comment: Thankyou Valentino, this is perfect and I appreciate the explanation as to why what I had didn't work. Thank you!